# Efficient algorithm to find frequency of words, max word frequency and total word count

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, search

I am trying to find frequencies of each word occurring in a section of a file and total word count of that section. 
For example if there's a file: file.txt:

> This is a file section which is part of the file.
>   #
>   This is another file section which is part of the same file separated by hash.

I wish to find frequency of each word, which word has maximum frequency and total word count in each section in an efficient manner. Such that:

> In Section 1: This-1; is-2; a-1; file-2; section-1; which-1; part-1; of-1; the-1| Total Words: 11| Word having Maximum Frequency: is,file
>   In Section 2: This-1; is-2; another-1; file-2; section-1; which-1; part-1; of-1; the-1; same-1; by-1; hash-1;| Total Words:15| Words having Maximum Frequency: is,file

So far, I have come up with a loop which goes through each word, increases the Total Word Count, then put each word in a Key/Value Pair having frequency of each word. I don't know about maximum frequency. Is there any efficient algorithm which I could try to use?

I wish to do so in Java. So, I was thinking of using HashMaps but any better approach is welcome.

Thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like a perfect scenario for applying MapReduce: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html ; for the frequency you can simply use `wordCountOfWorkxyz / totalWords`.

Comment: That seems good. Is there a method to find key having maximum frequency in MapReduce? Total Words, I suppose I could find using normal iterative variable.

Comment: You don't have to use MapReduce for this task, I just suggested it, because it is a common scenario and sometimes people like to learn new things. You can simply stick to your algorithm as long as the files isn't huge. The interesting thing is that maximum frequency does not even matter if it is calculated over the whole section. The word that occurred the most times will also have the highest frequency.

Comment: Have you had a look on solutions already provided on SO? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+frequency+words If so.

Comment: @tbrown Oh sure. My file isn't that big. I was looking for something that might take O(n) time to do everything which includes tokenizing, Hashmaps with frequency, total word count, and **dividing into sections**.

Comment: @SubOptimal Yes, I did. But the solutions provided don't deal with total word counts and sub sections inside the same file. I also wanted to know about any efficient algorithm that exist.

Comment: [Guava `Multiset`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) might be an option

Comment: Keep `lastSeenInSection` number and  `numSeenPerSection` counter in each value in the hash map. Use a global section counter to determine the current section. If a word has `lastSeenInSection==currentSection` increment the counter; else restart counting from zero. Use a pair of variable to remember the max freq word in the section so far and its frequency; on each new word, check if they must be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily keep track of the current maximum as you update each word. For example, your loop for each section:

```
Initialize HashMap of Words
maxWord = null  // word with current max count
while not end of section
    get word
    if word in Words
        increment count of word in HashMap
    else
        add to Words with count of 1
    if maxWord == null || Words[word].Count > Words[maxWord].Count
        maxWord = word
end while
```

When you complete processing the section, you have the frequencies of all the words, and `maxWord` contains the word with the largest count.

The entire algorithm is O(n). You can do it in a single pass of the file.

Much simpler, though, to just build your `HashMap` of words and, at the end of each section, go sequentially through it to pick out the one that has the max count. That, too, is considered O(n).